# Ruby koans's assertion on test_hash_is_unordered

Tags: ruby, hash

In Ruby 1.9 a Hash is sorted on the basis of order of insertion.
Why the Ruby koans's assertion on test_hash_is_unordered method returns true?

To me, the method's title is quite misleading... maybe it refers to the fact that Ruby will recognize 2 equal hashes that were created with different keys order insetions.

But, theorically, this kind of assertion:

```
hash1 = { :one => "uno", :two => "dos" }
hash2 = { :two => "dos", :one => "uno" }

assert_equal ___, hash1 == hash2
```

Should return false. Or not?

Comment: Order is *preserved*, but it's "unordered" (i.e., order doesn't matter) when testing for equivalence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-3D-3D):

> **`hsh == other_hash → true or false`**
>
> Equality—Two hashes are equal if they each contain the same number of keys and if each key-value pair is equal to (according to `Object#==`) the corresponding elements in the other hash.

So two Hashes are considered equal if they have the same key/value pairs regardless of order.

The examples in the documentation even contain this:

```
h2 = { 7 => 35, "c" => 2, "a" => 1 }
h3 = { "a" => 1, "c" => 2, 7 => 35 }
h2 == h3   #=> true
```

Yes, the `test_hash_is_unordered` title is somewhat misleading as order isn't specifically being testing, only order with respect to equality is being demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a question of what 'unordered' means in such a context.

As a human, I would find it very difficult to compare two sets if they were not in order. The problem is that I can not easily match up identical elements and see if the sets are equivalent. Unless the sets happened to be listed in the same order, I would see them as unequal. This seems to be the conclusion that you came to also.

However, the thing is that the order of items in a mathematical concept of a set is simply *unimportant*. There is no way to 'order' the items, so two sets are identical if they contain the same elements. The set items are unordered, but they are are not 'out of order'; the concept of order does not apply.

I suppose that this is encapsulated entirely in the expression 'hash_is_unordered' but that was not immediately obvious to me, at least!